# Can´t restore a database from a backup

Tags: sql-server-2012-express

I reinstalled SQL Server Management Studio in my computer, then I'm trying to restore all backups.

Unfortunately, I get an error when trying to open one.

[image]

What should I do?, How do I set the BackupDirectory in my Settings?

Comment: Try this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/3ba6d023-5899-4c5a-9270-87792840a3ba/insufficient-access-rights-error-when-doing-backup?forum=sqlsmoanddmo

Comment: I now think that the problem is a little bigger. I found that Sql Management Studio actually was displaying the following message "Property MasterDBPath is not available". I think I should try it first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just installed Sql Server Express 2012 Sp1, and problem solved